# How to show the last row of the UITableView that hides under the input accessory view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView with a NavigationController and an InputAccessoryView. The UITableView scrolls to the bottom when it is loaded.The scroll works but the last row hides under the InputAccessoryView. My code for scroll is displayed below:

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
```

How can I show the last row?

Comment: You have to adjust the table height and then you have to set the new content offset otherwise it will never scroll to the last rows because they aren't visibile

Comment: **This is what worked for me:**
Instead of using `UIViewController`, I'm using `UITableViewController`
Secondly in `viewDidLoad()` I added `self.tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .automatic`
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

before you scroll to bottom ，first do remember to make your tableView hight enough：

```
self.tableView.height += self.inputBgView.height;
```

BTW，you can use another way to scroll to bottom animated

```
- (void)tableViewScrollToBottomAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    NSInteger numberOfRows = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0];
    if (numberOfRows) {
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:numberOfRows-1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:animated];
    }
}
```

then use like

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self tableViewScrollToBottomAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: i have multiple sections on my uitableview.

Answer (score 0):

InputAccessoryView of a textField or something for editing, a view above your keyboard?

if so you need to manually just your frame from that somthing like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
        //..
        // add observers
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:)
                                                     name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                                   object:nil];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    [self keyboardShown:YES withHeight:keyboardSize.height]; // add your InputAccessoryViews height here..
}

- (void)keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    [self keyboardShown:NO withHeight:keyboardSize.height]; // add your InputAccessoryViews height here..
}

- (void)keyboardShown:(BOOL)isShown withHeight:(CGFloat)height
{
    // adjust your frame here..

    CGRect tableTempFrame = tableView.frame;

    if (isShown)
        tableTempFrame.size.height -= height; 

    else
        tableTempFrame.size.height += height;

    // updates the frame of your tableView
    tableView.frame = tableTempFrame;

    CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(0, tableView.contentSize.height - tableView.frame.size.height);
    // scrolling to bottom
    [tableView setContentOffset:offset animated:YES];

}
//dont forget to removethe observers
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}
```

Another thing..

`[tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, CGFLOAT_MAX)];`

Does not work when using auto layout, instead use:

```
CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(0, tableView.contentSize.height - tableView.frame.size.height);
[tableView setContentOffset:offset animated:YES];
```

Hope i've helped you.. Have a good day, happy coding.. Cheers..

Comment: I tried your code but there is no change in the result.

Comment: hmm.. yes i think i got what your missing here.. wait.. i'll edit my answer later..

Comment: i am not showing the keyboard when the view launches. i have textview at the bottom of uitableview and the last row is hiding under textview.

Comment: subtract the height of the textview from your tableview then.. is it the footer of your table?

Comment: no the textview is not the footer of uitableview. uitableview and textview are subview of a view.

Comment: okay, just subract the height of uitableview with the height of the textview..
can you post your code?

Comment: subtract the height of uitableview?? textview height is 40.0f.

Comment: hmm.. yes.. 

tableView.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width, currentHeight - 40);

can you post your code for declaring from or maybe it is from storyboard?

Comment: in case your using storyboard:

reconfigure the height of your tableView inside `- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews` 

if not(programmatically) set the (height of your tableView - 40)

Comment: yes i am using storyboard. I have creating the uitableview exactly like you have suggested i.e ` tableView.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width, currentHeight - 40)` but its not inside `- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews`

Comment: if you want to change it run time `- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews` since i dont know what are you trying to do.. it wont update if its not inside the `- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews`, try playing with your code, good luck.. i'll be traveling back home.. hmm.. Good luck to you sir, i'll check this tomorrow if you figure this out..

Comment: I solved it. I had `setAutoresizingMask` on the uitableview. I disabled that and also I set the uitableview's frame to `CGRect tableFrame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 80.0f);` (height - 80.0f; 40.0f  for navigation controller height and another 40.0f for subview height). Thanks for your help.

Comment: okay.. congrats! i didnt realized you didn't deduct the navigationcontrollers height.. (y) glad i helped// :)